# Discord.py: Check if user has role ID from list not working

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

I'm currently making a reaction role configuration for my Discord.py bot, and I came across an issue trying to blacklist users from picking up roles. Here is my code:

```py
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT blacklists FROM reactionroles WHERE message_id = {payload.message_id} AND emojis = '{reaction}'")

    blacklist_result = cursor.fetchone()

    member = payload.member

    rolesUserHas = member.roles
    rolesIDuserHas = []

    for role in rolesUserHas:
      rolesIDuserHas.append(role.id)
      print(rolesIDuserHas)

    if any(item in blacklist_result for item in rolesIDuserHas):
      await member.send(f'{x_mark} You are blacklisted from picking up roles from that message.')
      return
    else:
      pass
```

However when I give myself a blacklisted role, it doesn't cancel or dm me, it just continues the process, as if it thinks I don't have the role. No errors are given, and I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: imho this question belongs on github : https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues

Comment: SQL results are fetched as _rows_, implemented as lists.  `blacklist_result` is actually a list of one value.  So you want to use `blacklist_result = cursor.fetchone()[0]`

Comment: Does `blacklists` definitely contain the role IDs (as ints) that you're looking to blacklist? Do you have an error handler anywhere swallowing the error? Print out `blacklist_result` and `rolesIDuserHas` to see if there actually *are* any common IDs.

Comment: Also the obligatory warning about SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @JohnGordon Okay, so I tried what you recommended, and nothing changed, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Diggy. Yes, I am sure there are common objects. When doing what JohnGordon suggested, I get the error `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int`

Comment: So `blacklists` is a string type in the database, not an integer?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry for not saying that earlier.

Comment: `role.id` is an int. It won't __eq__ with a string. That's why you aren't getting any `True` values when doing `any()` I'd recommend converting the IDs from the db to ints. (Or the `role.id` to `str()`, but it's up to you.

Comment: Got it, thanks so much (: I'll try this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that everyone `id` attribute in discord.py is a base 10 integer, and not a string. Either convert your database results to integers, or the ids to strings:

```py
role_ids = list(map(str, [r.id for r in member.roles]))
```